# Validar si el formulario se diligenció - HTML/JQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Hola a todos estoy intentando validar si un formulario está completamente diligenciado, si lo está debe abrir la ventana modal, pero si no lo está no debe abrirla, el código que tengo valida pero una vez se le da aceptar a la alerta me abre la modal aún con campos vacíos, este es el código que tengo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
             <head>

             <meta charset="utf-8">

             <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
             <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
             <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
             <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
             </head>

                     <?php
                     $title ="Tutelas | ";
                     include "head.php";
                     include "sidebar.php"; 
                     ?>

<!--VALIDACION DEL FORMULARIO ANTES DE INGRESAR-->
              <script>                          
             function validar(form) {
            if (document.form.numdocumento.value==""  || document.form.nautorizacion.value=="" || document.form.entidad=="" ) {
            alert("algunos campos pueden estar vacios");
            return false;
            } else {
            return true;
            }
            }

       $('#validar').modal('show');
            </script>


                 <div class="right_col" role="main"> <!-- page content -->
                  <div class="">
                       <div class="page-title">
                           <div class="clearfix"></div>
                           <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

                               <div class="x_panel">
                                   <div class="x_title">
                                       <h2>Radicaciòn de Tutelas</h2>
                                       <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
                      <li><a class="collapse-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
                      </li>
                      <li><a class="close-link"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
                      </li>
                                       </ul>
                                       <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                   </div>


                                   <!--ACA INICIA EL FORMULARIO-->

                    <form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="">

          <div class="container">

         <div class="table-responsive" style="width:100%;">        
         <table class="table" style="border: 0px" style="width: 100%">
         <thead>
         <tr>

         <th>  <label><input required type="checkbox" id="documento" value="documento" name="documento"> Documento de Identidad</label>
                 </th>

        <th><label><input required  type="checkbox" id="formula" value="formula" name="formula"> Formula Original</label> </th>

        <th><label><input required type="checkbox" id="historia" value="historia" name="historia"> Historia Clínica</label></th> 
          </tr>
               </thead>
                    <tbody>
                          <tr>


                   <td> <label><input required type="checkbox" name="autorizacion" id="cbox1" value="autorizacion"> Autorización</div></label>  </td>
                   <td><input  type="date" id="myDate"  name="fecha"></td>
      <td>


             <label for="selec-eps">E.P.S: </label>
             <select required value="entidad" name="entidad">
             <option></option>
             <option value="1">Nueva E.P.S</option>
             <option value="2">Saludvida</option>
             <option value="3">Sociedad Clinica Emcosalud</option>
             <option value="4">Asmet Salud</option>
             <option value="5">Ferro Carriles Nacionales</option>
             </select>
             </td></tr>


             <tr><td> 
             <label for="selec-documento">Tipo de Documento: </label>
             <select required name="tidocumento">
             <option ></option>
             <option value="1">Cedula de Ciudadania</option>
             <option value="2">Tarjeta de Identidad</option>
             <option value="3">Registro Civil</option>
             </select>
             </td><td>


            <div style="width: 10px">
            <INPUT  id=text1 style="width: 141px; height: 20px" onkeypress="return valida(event)" size=32  placeholder="Numero Identidad"  name="numdocumento">
             </div></td>

             <td> 
             <label for="selec-tutela"> Tipo de Tutela: </label>

             <select name="tutela" required id="select-tutela" >
             <option></option>
             <option value="1">Tutela Pos</option>
             <option value="2">Tutela No Pos</option>
             </select>
             </td></tr>

            <tr><td>
           <INPUT  id=text1 style="width: 150px; height: 20px" onkeypress="return valida(event)" size=32   placeholder="Numero de Autorizacion" name="nautorizacion">
          <!--agegar campos de numero de autorización-->
          <form id="form" name="form" method="post">
          <a href="#" onclick="AgregarCampos();"> + Autorizaciòn</a>
          <div id="campos">
          <br>

             <script type="text/javascript">
             var nextinput = 0;
             function AgregarCampos(){
             nextinput++;
              autorizacion  =  '<li id="rut'+nextinput+'">Autorizaciòn  <input type="text"  size="20" id="campo' + nextinput + '"&nbsp; name="campo' + nextinput + '"&nbsp; /></li> <p>';
              $("#campos").append(autorizacion);
              }
             </script>
             <!--aca caba temina la funcion para agregar los campos-->


             <p>
              </td>
              <td>
              <textarea style="width:250px; height: 60px" name="observaciones" value="observaciones" placeholder="Observaciones" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea>
             </td> 
             <td></td>
             <thead>
             <tr>
             <th></th>
             <th>

                 <!--boton que abre la ventana modal-->
                <button  id="myBtnEnviar" type="submit" value="Enviar" onclick="validar();"
               class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#miModal" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">RADICAR</button>
                </th></tr>


               <!--aca termina el formulario-->






               <!--inicio de ventana modal -->
               </thead></p>
                  <div class="modal fade" id="miModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Registro Médico</h4>
                   </div>
                   <div class="modal-body">


              <div class="form-group" >
                  <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" style="text-align: center;">Registro Médico Nº <span class="required"></span>
                  </label>


                  <div style="text-align: center;" > <INPUT style="text-align: center;" id=text1 style="width:150px; height: 20px" onkeypress="return valida(event)" size=32 name=text1 
                  placeholder="Digite Registro Medico">
                  </INPUT></div>

                   <p></p>
                   <br></br>
                   </div> <div style="text-align: center;"> <button style="text-align: center;" id="save_data" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Guardar</button>



                  </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
           <!--Fin de la Ventana modal-->

                 </div>
                 </div> </th>
                 <th></th> 
                 </tr>
                 </thead>





         <script>
         function valida(e){
        tecla = (document.all) ? e.keyCode : e.which;

        //Tecla de retroceso para borrar, siempre la permite
        if (tecla==8){
        return true;
        }

           // Patron de entrada, en este caso solo acepta numeros
           patron =/[0-9]/;
           tecla_final = String.fromCharCode(tecla);
           return patron.test(tecla_final);
                          }
                   </script>
                 </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

```
                      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/project.js"></script>
                      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/VentanaCentrada.js"></script>
                      <script>
                       $( "#add" ).submit(function( event ) {
                       $('#save_data').attr("disabled", true);

                        var parametros = $(this).serialize();
                           $.ajax({
                           type: "POST",
                           url: "action/addproject.php",
                           data: parametros,
                           beforeSend: function(objeto){
                           $("#result").html("Mensaje: Cargando...");
                            },
                           success: function(datos){
                           $("#result").html(datos);
                           $('#save_data').attr("disabled", false);
                           load(1);
                           }});
                           event.preventDefault();
                           })

                          // success

                         $( "#upd" ).submit(function( event ) {
                         $('#upd_data').attr("disabled", true);

                        var parametros = $(this).serialize();
                        $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "action/updproject.php",
                        data: parametros,
                        beforeSend: function(objeto){
                        $("#result2").html("Mensaje: Cargando...");
                        },
                        success: function(datos){
                         $("#result2").html(datos);
                        $('#upd_data').attr("disabled", false);
                        load(1);
                            }
                          });
                          // event.preventDefault();
                           })

                         function obtener_datos(id){
                         var description = $("#description"+id).val();
                         var name = $("#name"+id).val();
                         $("#mod_id").val(id);
                         $("#mod_description").val(description);
                         $("#mod_name").val(name);
                         }
                         </script>
```

Comment: Hola bienvenido a Stackoverflow ES. Te recomiendo hacer el recorrido: [Tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Además para mejor solución/respuesta lee: [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Tu código es algo confuso, si lo puedes arreglar sería estupendo. Lo que ví por encima es que tienes dos formularios con el mismo ID. Prueba poniendo la línea `$('#validar').modal('show');` dentro del `else` donde validas los campos.

Comment: hola no, solo tengo un formulario, y el que hace que valide es esto:   <script>                          
                function validar(form) {
                if (document.form.numdocumento.value==""  || document.form.nautorizacion.value=="" ) {
                alert("algunos campos pueden estar vacios");
                return false;
                } else {
                return true;
                }
                } 
     
                </script>

Answer (score 0):

Mira, este es el codigo que hace que valide

```
<script>                          
function validar(form) {
  if (document.form.numdocumento.value==""  || document.form.nautorizacion.value=="" ) {
    alert("algunos campos pueden estar vacios");
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
}
} 

</script>
```